# Show base64 string PDF in a Webview in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

I am getting base64 data from the server. I want to show that in a Webview. Tried the below methods but not working

```
    web_pdf.loadData(decodedContent.toString(), "application/pdf", "charset=UTF-8");
```

Any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

> WebView does not support showing PDF files (besides using external
> services like the Google Docs viewer which requires an URL to the PDF
> file). You have to choose another method. Just search the web for
> something like "android show pdf".

will help.